# iOS text field doesn't show placeholder text

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

So I have some basic textfields with a custom background, that is a line at the bottom and the rest of it it's transparent, but now the placeholders don't show anymore.

These are the text fields

[image]

And config

[image]

Comment: Do you see the placeholder in your storyboard?

Comment: try to change the background color of your textfields

Comment: @MarieDm No I can't see them in xcode

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution that works, you need to select the input and set the following on **User Defined Runtime Attributes**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's better to do this:

```
if ([self.textField respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedPlaceholder:)]) {
    self.textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.textField.placeholder attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Turns out it had nothing to do with me having set `borderStyle` to `UITextBorderStyleNone`. It was caused by me subclassing `UITextField` to add a manually drawn border along the bottom only and failing to call the super implementation in my override of `layoutSubviews`. Once I had sorted that, my placeholder text was back.

Comment: had the same issue and confirm adding `super.layoutSubviews()` solve the issue. thanks